# Display values from list

Tags: android, list, android-listview

I have created an application in which i get information from Json Array.I parse it and store it.
Now I want to display this info in a ListView but I am getting null pointer exception.

SearchValue(Class to store array info)

```
public class SearchValues {

    public String address,applications,counts,contactInfo,email,expSummary,gender,IjobReqId,area,city,code,country,description,expDate,hours,state,status,title,type,maxExp,minExp,noOfPos,postedon,religion,requestorName,category;
}
```

SearchJobsCustomList(Custom List view)

```
 public class SearchJobsCustomList extends BaseAdapter {
    Context c;
    List<SearchValues> valueSearch;

    public SearchJobsCustomList(Context c, List<SearchValues> valueSearch) {
        super ();
        this.c = c;
        this.valueSearch = valueSearch;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return valueSearch.size ();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        SearchValues values = valueSearch.get (i);
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from (c).inflate (R.layout.custom_search_jobs_lists, viewGroup, false);
            TextView JobCode = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_job_code);
            TextView Category = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_category);
            TextView ExpYrs = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_exp_yrs);
            TextView ExpMnths = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_exp_mnths);
            TextView Date = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_date);


            JobCode.setText (values.code);
            Category.setText (values.category);
            ExpYrs.setText (values.minExp);
            ExpMnths.setText (values.maxExp);
            Date.setText (values.postedon);





        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

SearchJobLists

```
public class SearchJobsList extends Activity {


    SearchJobsCustomList searchJobsCustomList;
    private ListView lvresources;
    private Context c = this;
    List<SearchValues> valuesS;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.search_job_lists);
        initialize ();

    }


    private void initialize() {

        lvresources = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listView);
        searchJobsCustomList = new SearchJobsCustomList (c, valuesS);
        lvresources.setAdapter (searchJobsCustomList);
    }
}
```

SearchJobs(from where i m getting Json)

```
public class SearchJobsAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String response;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            response = HttpRequest.post ("https://beta135.hamarisuraksha.com/web/WebService/HsJobService.asmx/FindJobForVendor").send ("Vendor_IEntity_Code=" + "89F00539-25EA-E311-853B-000C29762494" + "&Job_Code=" + "" + "&Job_Category=" + strCategory + "&Exp_Years_From=" + strYrs + "&Exp_Months_From=" + strMnths + "&Exp_Years_To=" + strToYrs + "&Exp_Months_To=" + strToMnths).body ();
            //Vendor_IEntity_Code=string&Job_Code=string&Job_Category=string&Exp_Years_From=string&Exp_Months_From=string&Exp_Years_To=string&Exp_Months_To=string
            response = response.replaceAll ("<[^>]*>", "").replaceAll ("\n", "");
            Log.e ("Response", "" + response);
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute (s);
            SearchValues values = new SearchValues ();
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject (s);
                NewDataSet = jsonObject.getJSONObject ("NewDataSet");
                if (NewDataSet == null) {
                    Toast.makeText (SearchJobs.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                } else if (NewDataSet.get ("Table") instanceof JSONObject) {
                    JSONObject table = NewDataSet.getJSONObject ("Table");
                    values.address = table.getString ("Address");
                    values.applications = table.getString ("Applications");
                    values.counts = table.getString ("Candidate_Counts");
                    values.contactInfo = table.getString ("Contact_No");
                    values.email = table.getString ("Email");
                    values.expSummary = table.getString ("Exp_Summary");
                    values.gender = table.getString ("Gender_Name");
                    values.IjobReqId = table.getString ("IJob_Request_ID");
                    values.area = table.getString ("Job_Area");
                    values.category = table.getString ("Job_Category");
                    values.city = table.getString ("Job_City");
                    values.code = table.getString ("Job_Code");
                    values.country = table.getString ("Job_Country");
                    values.description = table.getString ("Job_Desc");
                    values.expDate = table.getString ("Job_Exp_Date");
                    values.hours = table.getString ("Job_Hours");
                    values.state = table.getString ("Job_State");
                    values.status = table.getString ("Job_Status");
                    values.title = table.getString ("Job_Title");
                    values.type = table.getString ("Job_Type");
                    values.maxExp = table.getString ("Max_Exp");
                    values.minExp = table.getString ("Min_Exp");
                    values.noOfPos = table.getString ("No_Of_Pos");
                    values.postedon = table.getString ("Posted_On");
                    values.religion = table.getString ("Religion_Name");
                    values.requestorName = table.getString ("Requestor_Name");


                } else if (NewDataSet.get ("Table") instanceof JSONArray) {
                    JSONArray tablearray = NewDataSet.getJSONArray ("Table");
                    for (int i = 0; i< tablearray.length (); i++) {
                        JSONObject table = tablearray.getJSONObject (i);
                        values.address = table.getString ("Address");
                        values.applications = table.getString ("Applications");
                        values.counts = table.getString ("Candidate_Counts");
                        values.contactInfo = table.getString ("Contact_No");
                        values.email = table.getString ("Email");
                        values.expSummary = table.getString ("Exp_Summary");
                        values.gender = table.getString ("Gender_Name");
                        values.IjobReqId = table.getString ("IJob_Request_ID");
                        values.area = table.getString ("Job_Area");
                        values.category = table.getString ("Job_Category");
                        values.city = table.getString ("Job_City");
                        values.code = table.getString ("Job_Code");
                        values.country = table.getString ("Job_Country");
                        values.description = table.getString ("Job_Desc");
                        values.expDate = table.getString ("Job_Exp_Date");
                        values.hours = table.getString ("Job_Hours");
                        values.state = table.getString ("Job_State");
                        values.status = table.getString ("Job_Status");
                        values.title = table.getString ("Job_Title");
                        values.type = table.getString ("Job_Type");
                        values.maxExp = table.getString ("Max_Exp");
                        values.minExp = table.getString ("Min_Exp");
                        values.noOfPos = table.getString ("No_Of_Pos");
                        values.postedon = table.getString ("Posted_On");
                        values.religion = table.getString ("Religion_Name");
                        values.requestorName = table.getString ("Requestor_Name");



                    }


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }
//            Intent i = new Intent (SearchJobs.this, SearchJobsList.class);
//            startActivity (i);
        }
    }


}
```

LOGCAT

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.jobs_on_call_adapter.SearchJobsCustomList.getCount(SearchJobsCustomList.java:31)
            at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:465)
            at com.example.jobs_on_call_search_jobs.SearchJobsList.initialize(SearchJobsList.java:38)
            at com.example.jobs_on_call_search_jobs.SearchJobsList.onCreate(SearchJobsList.java:29)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Now where i went wrong please correct me.Also if you can give me any suggestion on how to store information from JSON(array or object) and den use it somewhere else.

Comment: In `searchJobsCustomList = new SearchJobsCustomList (c, valuesS);`, what is `valuesS`? It is null. That's why you are getting NPE

Comment: how to solve it plz can you help???

Comment: You need to have a constructor in `SearchValues` and in that initialise all the string values. Then `valuesS.add(new SearchValues()) `

Comment: problem is you did no defined value to `valuesS` object, so its still null..

Comment: then i will have to add all the fields from SearchValues class cos all r imp.Can u suggest me other method where i can store info from json(array or object) and use it to display data in the listView

Comment: If you can show the code from where you are getting the JSON values then it will be easy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should write `valuesS = new List<SearchValues>();` in `OnCreate` before `initialize ();` (no more NullPointerException) and add some data in this List when parsing JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you are creating object of SearchJobsCustomList, you have not defined valuesS values, you have just defined that type of variable.

searchJobsCustomList = new SearchJobsCustomList (c, valuesS);

It seems you would like to show your json data as valuesS, to order do it create a list object and push all your values in it from database or from from where you are getting as json data.

rest are fine to populate items in list view.

Comment: i have stored my json data like 
SearchValues values=new SerachValues();
values.address=jsonObj.getString.......
Like this i hav stored the values from array and when i call tv.setText(values.address) in the customList i am not getting anyThing

Comment: Can you check logs for values.address, is it empty or having address value in it??   Log.d("address value", values.address);

Comment: when parsing json it is having valuesa in it but when i call it in the listView class i m nt getting anything

Comment: Can you please change this in your initialize() method.

        lvresources = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listView);
        SearchValues valuesS = new SearchValues();
        searchJobsCustomList = new SearchJobsCustomList (c, valuesS);
        lvresources.setAdapter (searchJobsCustomList);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change this in your initialize() method as seems you are passing null object of Searchvalues.

```
lvresources = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listView);
SearchValues valuesS = new   SearchValues();
searchJobsCustomList = new SearchJobsCustomList (c, valuesS);
lvresources.setAdapter (searchJobsCustomList); }
```